# Global Variable problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I define a global variable flag in global.h file,when i click next tab bar then i can not access the flag value.I want a global variable for all tabs.please suggest me.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a global variable, here are some options you can try:

**1) Define static variables in global.h. E.g. you want to have a NSString global variable, declare the following in global.h:**

```
@interface global : NSObject {

}
+(NSString*)MY_STR;

@end
```

Then implement it as static in global.m:

```
static NSString* MY_STR;

@implementation global

+(void) initialize
{

MY_STR = @"global string";      

}

+(NSString*)MY_STR{
    return MY_STR;
}
```

Then in any class that needs this variable,  you can import global.h and access it as below:

```
[global MY_STR];
```

**2) In this approach, define a singleton class and use its properties.
You can create global as a singleton class. Declare a static getInstance method in global.h:**

```
@interface global : NSObject{
  NSString *MY_STR;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *MY_STR;
+(global*)getInstance;
@end
```

In global.m, declare a static sharedInstance:

```
@implementation global

@synthesize MY_STR;

static global *g;

+(global*)getInstance{
    @synchronized([global class]){
        if(g == nil){
            g = [[global alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return g;   
}

@end
```

In any class that needs to access MY_STR, import global.h and write the following:

```
global *g1= [global getInstance];
g1.MY_STR;
```

**3) The third approach would be to declare variables in app delegate and access them.**

Answer (score 2):

for a  (not-objective) c approach:

in global.h

```
extern int flag;
```

in global.m

```
int flat;
```

in any other .m or .c

```
#import "global.h"

flag = 123; // set
int abc = flag; // get
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include this file into place where you want to use this flag?

Answer (score 0):

Use Getter and Setter Method for each Tab's click event.

```
-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)newTitle {

    if (instanceVar != newTitle) {
    [instanceVar release]; 
    instanceVar = [newTitle copy];
    // or retain, depending on object & usage
    }
 }


 -(NSString *)title {

       return [[instanceVar retain] autorelease];
     }
```

Comment: use + sign instead of - for global purpose and set the value like this:[className setTitle:@"abc"]; and use this value throughout the application using [classname title]; method.